# Is there a way to read Outlook emails with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, outlook

I need to use Google Apps Script to read emails from Outlook whenever a new email comes in so that it can be transferred to Gsheets. I tried using Outlook to automatically email them to a Gmail account but it's from a company email and the admin might have restricted it for security purposes.

Comment: Outlook.com? What is the underlying email server? If you are on a Mac you can do this pretty easily with AppleScript and Google Apps Script. If you are on a PC, you are going to have a hard time doing this from Outlook as a front end.

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script has access to Google things... Gmail, Google Sheets, etc.

How about an IFTTT applet? Looks like there's one out there that does what you want:

https://ifttt.com/applets/415798p-outlook-email-to-google-spreadsheet